# Pervasive ODBC access from PHP on Linux?

Tags: php, pervasive

Can anyone give me an example of querying a Pervasive PSQL database from PHP on a remote Linux machine?

Pervasive claims PHP can access it, but their examples use Windows COM objects, which isn't available on Linux, and the first "PHP DTO Extensions 1" link they have for download actually links to a bunch of ASP .NET scripts, and isn't even PHP at all:
[Pervasive PHP Examples](http://ww1.pervasive.com/developerzone/development_env/php.asp)

Answer (score 2):

I'll let Pervasvive know they need to change the sample.  I've got some contacts there.  As for using PSQL from a Linux box, you don't mention what version of PSQL you are using but you'll need the PSQL client for Linux.  Here's a sample I've used before to test connectivity from PHP on Linux (and WIndows) to a PSQL server.  In the odbc_connect, the "Demodata" is the ODBC DSN name.  The other two parameters are user name and password.  You would need to compile (or enable) ODBC in PHP.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>PHP Sample</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
$conn=odbc_connect("Demodata","","",""); 
$sql="select * from class";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);  
echo "<table border=1>\n";
$numfields = odbc_num_fields($rs);
for($i=1;$i<=$numfields;$i++){
    $fn=odbc_field_name($rs,$i);
    echo "<th>$fn</th>";
}
echo "\n";
while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)){ 
    echo "<tr>\n";
    for($i=1;$i<=$numfields;$i++){
       $fv=odbc_result($rs,$i);
       echo "<td>$fv</td>";
    }   
    echo "</tr>\n";
} 
echo "</table>\n";
echo "<p>Number of Fields: $numfields</p>\n";
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is the PDO extension http://nl.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php it can connect to any database which supports ODBC

Answer (score 0):

If you can install something on the Pervasive Server you can try using odbtp. It is a bridge between an ODBC driver on the server and clients that can run on Linux or Windows. a query example from php taken from [here](http://odbtp.sourceforge.net/examples.html) is

```
<?php

$con = odbtp_connect( 'odbtp.somewhere.com',
                      'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myserver;UID=myuid;PWD=mypwd;DATABASE=mydb;' ) or die;

odbtp_set_attr( ODB_ATTR_FULLCOLINFO, TRUE );

$qry = odbtp_query( $_REQUEST['query'] ) or die;

do {
    if( ($msg = odbtp_get_message( $qry )) ) {
        echo "MESSAGE: $msg<p>";
        continue;
    }
    if( ($cols = odbtp_num_fields( $qry )) == 0 ) {
        echo odbtp_affected_rows( $qry );
        echo " rows affected<p>\n";
        continue;
    }
    echo "<table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 border=1>\n";
    echo "<tr>";
    for( $col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++ ) {
        echo "<td><nobr> " . odbtp_field_name( $qry, $col );
        echo " (" . odbtp_field_type( $qry, $col ) . ") </nobr></td>";
        if( odbtp_field_bindtype( $qry, $col ) == ODB_DATETIME )
            odbtp_bind_field( $qry, $col, ODB_CHAR );
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";

    while( ($rec = odbtp_fetch_array($qry)) ) {
        echo "<tr>";
        for( $col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++ ) {
            if( is_null( $rec[$col] ) ) $rec[$col] = "NULL";
            echo "<td><nobr> $rec[$col] </nobr></td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table><p>\n";

    echo odbtp_affected_rows( $qry );
    echo " rows affected<p>\n";
}
while( odbtp_next_result( $qry ) );

odbtp_close(); ?>
```