# How to connect Pervasive ODBC using PHP on Windows?

Tags: php, pervasive

I want to Connect Pervasive ODBC using PHP on Windows. Wether we have to download Pervasive client version for same? Whats else we need to download for this?

Answer (score 1):

To access Pervasive data through PHP, you will need either the client or the engine depending on where the data is in relation to where PHP is running.  If PHP is running on a machine where the Pervasive data is located, you need the Pervasive engine.  If the data is on a different machine, you'll probably need the Pervasive client.

From PHP, you can use ODBC to access the Pervasive engine.  Here's a link to Pervasive's site:
<strike>http://ww1.pervasive.com/developerzone/development_env/php.asp</strike>
edit: Looks like the link has changed since 2010.  The current link is http://www.pervasive.com/database/Home/Support/PSQLSDKArchives.aspx but I wasn't able to download the PHP sample.  It's possible it's been removed.  The sample was a simple PHP page connecting to ODBC. Here's a sample that is the same as what was on the Pervasive site: [Pervasive ODBC access from PHP on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251334/pervasive-odbc-access-from-php-on-linux?rq=1)